# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом И в предложении: "Смой и увидишь свою красоту"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и" в предложении: "Смой и увидишь свою красоту".

Answer (score 1):

***Смой, и увидишь свою красоту.***

Это определенно-личные односоставные предложения, но по грамматике они неоднородны (разное наклонение, повелительное и изъявительное).

Поэтому их нельзя приравнять к однородным членам, запятая ставится.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Молясь, дети Божии открывают Ему свои мысли, надежды и скорби. «**Просите, и дано будет вам, ищите, и найдете, стучите, и отворят вам»** [Александр Мень. Сын Человеческий (1969)]

Фразу эту **пишут по-разному**: с запятой,  без запятой, через тире.

2) Но здесь только два глагола, в то время как в заданном предложении **второй глагол имеет свои второстепенные члены,** а это **способствует проявлению неоднородности** в отношениях между сказуемыми.

**Пауза** в заданном предложении явно присутствует, поэтому предложение следует считать **сложносочиненным.**

3) Обозначать паузу тире нет необходимости, так как **запятой вполне достаточно.** Постановка тире регламентируется специальными правилами http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже так думала. Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы здесь поставил тире. Второе предложение следствие первого.
***Смой - и увидишь свою красоту.***

Что касается запятой, то она выглядит спорной.  Вроде бы и смотрится без неё плохо, но обоснование "неоднородности" явно недостаточно.
В нацкорпусе есть много примеров подобных фраз, запятая не везде есть. Правда там и контекст не точно такой же... Но в общих чертах там так. Если глаголы выражают действие - результат, то они они вполне себе "однородны": "смотри и увидишь", "слушай и услышишь", "ищите и найдете". Запятая обычно не ставится.

В отношении же вашей пары "смой и увидишь" сказать наверняка трудно. Поэтому тире - идеальный выход из ситуации. Тем более, что и объективный мотив для его постановки имеется.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Думаю, что и тире можно поставить.